# alternative for saxon:assign and saxon:assignable

Tags: java, saxon

I am trying to upgrade my project to Java 8 and my project uses Saxon old version (i think saxon9). I was getting some issue after upgrading my project to Java 8 and in saxonia said Java 8 issues fixed in Saxon 9.5 version, so I have changed to Saxon HE 9.7 and supposed to use HE version alone. The inbuilt functions saxon:assign and saxon:assignable moved to EE version it seems.

So I am looking for an alternative approach to achieve saxon:assign and saxon:assignable.

Any suggestions? or any working examples would be helpful.

My Requirement is same as stated in https://www.altova.com/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=1000001577 .. How to increase variable count? without using saxon:assign and saxon:assignable.

I want have a global variable and need to increment when processing the element.

Updating more info.This is my requirement.
My Input xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employees>
    <employee>
        <name>Anbu</name>
        <address>Chennai</address>
        <dob>1990-05-15</dob>
        <phone>9600096000</phone>
        <email>anbu@email.com</email>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Bala</name>
        <address>Hydrabad</address>
        <dob>1989-01-04</dob>
        <phone>9700097000</phone>
        <email>bala@email.com</email>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Chandru</name>
        <address>Mumbai</address>
        <dob>1995-11-10</dob>
        <phone>9900099000</phone>
        <email>chandru@email.com</email>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

Need output like:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>Employee Details</h2>
      <table border="1">
         <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th style="text-align:left">Name</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Age</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Anbu</td>
            <td>1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Bala</td>
            <td>2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Chandru</td>
            <td>3</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

I want to have a global variable and increment it. I have tried with below xsl, but not works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="count" select="0" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Employee Details</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th style="text-align:left">Name</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left">Age</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="employees/employee">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$count+1" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

can I achive this by creating Custom functions with ExtensionFunctionDefinition ?

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is to wean yourself off the use of mutable variables. This may need a different approach, but if you learn to think declaratively then everything is possible. The changes you need to make will depend very much on how and why you are using saxon:assign.

If you can't do that, an alternative is to use stateful (impure) extension functions.

The specific example in the Altova forum post that you cite can be done very easily without saxon:assign. It's a somewhat strange example because it appears to depend on the order of attributes, but you can do it like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="days" 
   select="'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'"/>

<xsl:variable name="orderedAtts" as="attribute()*">
  <xsl:perform-sort select="//content-list/@*">
    <xsl:sort select="index-of($days, name())"/>
  </xsl:perform-sort>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="$orderedAtts[.='true']">
  <xsl:value-of select="position(), name(), '&#xa;'"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

There are a few cases where `saxon:assign` can be really useful, but the vast majority of cases where it is used (including this one) are simply because the stylesheet author hasn't learnt to think declaratively rather than procedurally.

**LATER**

The second example you have posted is even simpler. All it needs is:

```
<xsl:for-each select="employee">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thank you Michael Sir, I have updated my question with the actual example. Could you provide your suggestion?